# How do I check whether string matches certain format?

Tags: java

I want to find out how to check whether string format matches

"111 + 222"

With string like this, format should be

(double type number)+(white space)+(operand(+,-,*,/,^))+(white space)+(double type number)

I know I should use matches to do that, but how do I process this with white space?

Comment: `if ("111 + -2.22".matches("(-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)\\s*[\\+\\-\\*\\/]\\s*(-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)")) { ... }`. Handles signed or unsigned Integer or floating point numerical values

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use a pattern matcher or string matches.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String pattern = "-?[\\d\\.]{3,4}\\s[+\\-*/^]\\s-?[\\d\\.]{3,4}";
    System.out.println(matchWithPatternMatcherCompile(pattern, "111 + 222")); // True
    System.out.println(matchWithPatternMatcher(pattern, "111 + 222")); // True
    System.out.println(matchWithStringRegex(pattern, "111 + 222")); // True
    System.out.println(matchWithPatternMatcherCompile(pattern, "111 + -2.22")); // True
    System.out.println(matchWithPatternMatcher(pattern, "11.1 + 222")); // True
    System.out.println(matchWithStringRegex(pattern, "-111 + 222")); // True
}

private static boolean matchWithStringRegex(String regex, String input) {
    return input.matches(regex);
}

private static boolean matchWithPatternMatcherCompile(String regex, String input) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    return matcher.matches();
}

private static boolean matchWithPatternMatcher(String regex, String input) {
    return Pattern.matches(regex, input);
}
```

Comment: Can I do it in one line? if (equation.matches("\\d\\s[+\\-*/^]\\s\\d")) like this.

Comment: yes: System.out.println(Pattern.compile("\\d{3}\\s[+\\-*/^]\\s\\d{3}").matcher("111 + 222").matches());

Comment: @EdLee, yes, `str.matches(regex)` yields exactly the same result as the expression `Pattern.matches(regex, str)`